# Preserve User ROIs after Analyze Particles Add to Manager

Tags: imagej, roi

I'm working primarily in the macro language.

For my macro, I am asking a user to select a few elements from an image. One is an ellipse selection and the other polygonal. I have these two ROIs in the ROI Manager and I would like to keep them.

When I do further analysis on the image to isolate different tissues I need to use analyze particles to add more ROIs to the ROI Manager, but when I add them, it erases the user selected ROIs.

Is there a way to append the ROIs to the list or do I need to reorder my macro?

```
run("Select None");             //Selecting nothing just in case
setTool(1);                     //Elliptical tool 

while (selectionType != 1) {
    message= "Elliptical Selection Required\n Please select the Peduncle Attachment Zone";
    waitForUser(message);
}

roiManager("Add"); 

// User selection of Seed Cavity
// hexagonal (polygon) selection
run("Select None");             //Selecting nothing just in case
setTool(2);                     //Elliptical tool 

while (selectionType != 2) {
    message= "Polygonal Selection Required\n Please select the Seed Cavity";
    waitForUser(message);
}

roiManager("Add");
run("Select None");             //clear current selection

//threshold here
//analyze particles
run("8-bit");
setThreshold(0, 128);
setOption("BlackBackground", false);
run("Convert to Mask");     
correctLUT();  //checks if inverted and corrects
run("Analyze Particles...", "size=55000-Infinity circularity=0.65-1.00 show=Masks display exclude add");

function correctLUT() {
    invertedLUT = is("Inverting LUT");
    if (invertedLUT == 1) {
        run("Invert LUT");
        run("Invert");
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your macro (commenting out `correctLUT()` though), and it keeps all the user-defined ROIs. Is this the complete code you are using?

Comment: Sadly no, this was supposed to be a reproducible example, but in my haste to post it is apparent that it does indeed work as it should. I could swear it wasn't though and I don't understand why. I have since reorganized my code to find what I needed to find first and then ask for user input, but it looks as though I didn't need to.

Comment: It looks as though my problem might have been a vestigial "clear" in the analyze particles command. run("Analyze Particles...", "size=20-Infinity circularity=0.5-1.00 show=Masks display exclude clear add"); does indeed clear not only the results table, it also clears the ROI manager, which is not mentioned in the online documentation. _Clear Results If checked, any previous measurements listed in the Results Table↑ will be cleared._

Comment: Good point. You might want to send a message to the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html) about the incomplete documentation. That list is usually the best place to ask about ImageJ, since many expert users and plugin developers are subscribed.